# Java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused, All Android Browsers wont connect to (https://t.co|https://g.co etc) links

Tags: java, android, https, socket.io, http-status-code-403

Hello I'm running Android 7.0 Nougat sdk 24 rooted and I'm having issues with all browsers connecting to https://t.co links from Twitter. I have used Android Studio logcat with the browsers and have confirmed its an issue with Java.net socket connection. I am getting errors such as:

```
Java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused –   
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178) at
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356) at
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
```

Comment: Thank you @user207421 for the edit, didn't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

if its not a production code then u need to add this to the application manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
```

else please read up on ssl pinning or set it under

```
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...>
```

Comment: Is the application manifest the same as AndroidManifest.xml ? Is this manifest on the application side or system side?

Comment: Yes, the file name is AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but this is not my own app with the issue. I believe it to be more of a System issue. I am more trying to find out a way how to compile signed certs from this repository https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/ca-certificates/+/master/files then import them into my phone as a recognized user or root CA.

Comment: UPDATE: Was able to download all of Root CA's from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/ca-certificates/+/master/files from tgz file,  signed .PEM files inside. I was able to update them into root Directory and System is able to recognize them. However, this did not solve my issue. Still getting connection refused from twitter redirect sites starting with https://www.t.co ; I was able to check with www.digicert.com/help to confirm my browser could connect. I DL duckduckgo browser with way better logcat & now able to confirm issue is with Java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)